# Question to find increment in total energy of a sample of He gas?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, enthalpy, heat

If a closed rigid wall container filled with 20 gram of Helium gas moving at a constant speed of 10 m/sec is stopped abruptly to stand still, find the increment in temperature of this He sample.

Way I have solved

I used Average kinetic energy formula and $nfRT/2$(f is degree of freedom here).

My sir told me that  $nfRT/2$ = Translational kinetic energy + Rotational kinetic energy.

So I used the formula  $nfRT/2$= ${\frac{1mv^2}{2}}$ + Rotational kinetic energy.

In the question , Rotational kinetic energy is not given.Rotational kinetic energy will be 0 here since He is has 3 degrees of freedom.

I get is Kinetic energy = $1/2 * 20/1000 * 10^2 =1

1 = $n3T/2$

Should I take n =1?Because it not given.

Have I solved it correctly and is there any other way to solve it.

Comment: Try to use more specific titles, as there are many questions about thermodynamics here. By 20 gm you probably mean g as gram.Include your complete computation procedure, and preferably use [MathJax](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here)  for formula formatting. Note that the goal of the site is not a task proof reading nor solving, but helping to understand principles. It also prefers elaborated question. Do you have troubles to understand or apply a particular principle ?

Comment: Always think  thoroughly about possible answers to your question and search for them
before asking, together with providing of your intermediate  results of the failure.

Comment: Yes.one is that whether n will =1? Second , what I have written , is it correct? Is there any other to approach this problem.

Comment: @Poutnik This is not there online.Made by sir itself.

Comment: @Poutnik It took me to some researchers site which had many things I didn’t even know or needed to study now.

Comment: Improvement of the question belongs to the question, not to comments. The principles to solve are on internet. How long have you been thinking about it and searching for ways to solve it ?

Comment: Almost an hour.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116451/discussion-between-poutnik-and-robert-patrick).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The total mechanical energy (other kinds of energy are ignored here ) of moving gas is the sum of potential energy and translational, rotational and vibrational kinetic energy :

$$E = E_\mathrm{pot} + E_\mathrm{trans} + E_\mathrm{vibr} + E_\mathrm{rot}$$

These energies can be separated as the energy of the bulk volume of a gas and the energy of gas molecules in the inertial frame where the centre of the gass mass is in the rest:

$$\small E = (E_\mathrm{pot,bulk} + E_\mathrm{pot,mol}) + (E_\mathrm{trans,bulk} + E_\mathrm{trans,mol}) \\ + (E_\mathrm{vibr,bulk} + E_\mathrm{vibr,mol}) + (E_\mathrm{rot,bulk}    + E_\mathrm{rot,mol})$$

We can for our case consider $E_\mathrm{pot,bulk} = 0$, $E_\mathrm{vibr,bulk} = 0$, $E_\mathrm{rot,bulk} = 0$, $E_\mathrm{pot,mol} = 0$, assuming zero bulk gas and molecular potential energy and no gas vibration nor rotation.

$$E = E_\mathrm{trans,bulk} + E_\mathrm{trans,mol} +   E_\mathrm{vibr,mol} +  E_\mathrm{rot,mol}$$

For the translational kinetic energy of the bulk gas is the notorious formula:

$$E_\mathrm{trans,bulk} = \frac 12 \cdot m \cdot v^2$$

We can with just a little error consider helium as an ideal gas. For 1 mole of an ideal gas, each [degree of freedom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degrees_of_freedom_(mechanics)) of motion has energy $E = \frac 12RT$, where $R \approx \pu{8.314 JK^-1mol^-1}$ is the universal gas constant and $T$ is absolute temperature. Their kinetic energy is then:

$$E_\mathrm{kin,mol}=\frac{f_\mathrm{trans} + f_\mathrm{vibr} + f_\mathrm{rot}}2RT$$

Atoms of monoatomic gasses like helium have 3 [degrees of freedom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degrees_of_freedom_(mechanics)) $f$ for translational motion, but do not rotate nor vibrate, so $f_\mathrm{vibr} = f_\mathrm{rot} = 0$

Therefore, the kinetic energy of helium  molecules of the total mass $m$ and molar mass $M$ , forming helium thermal energy is:
$$E_\mathrm{therm}=\frac {3mRT}{2M}$$

So we have finally the energy of the gaseous helium as:

$$E = \frac 12 \cdot m \cdot v^2 + \frac{3m}{2M}RT = \frac m2 \cdot ( v^2 + \frac{3RT}{M})$$

As the helium mass is constant and as we honour the law of energy conservation, the following equations must be true ( with indexes 1,2 as initial and final states:

$$v_1^2 + \frac{3RT_1}{M} =   v_2^2 + \frac{3RT_2}{M}$$

$$ \frac{3R}{M}(T_2 - T_1) =   v_1^2 - v_2^2$$

As the final speed $v_2 = 0$, we can write:

$$ \Delta T =   \frac {M \cdot v_1^2}{3R} $$

The helium molar mass $M \approx \pu{0.0040026 kg mol^-1} \approx \pu{0.004 kg mol^-1}$

$$ \Delta T =   \frac {M \cdot v_1^2}{3R} = \frac {(\pu{0.004 kg mol-1} ){(\pu{10 ms^-1})}^2}{\pu{3 \cdot 8.314 JK^-1mol^-1}} \approx \pu{+0.016 K}$$

---

For formatting of chem/math formulas/expressions, use can use [MathJax](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here), also look [here](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/86/4945)
and [here](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/443/which-symbols-are-written-in-roman-upright-font-and-which-are-italicized). See also [MathJax on Math SE](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).